Facebook Conversations Not Moving to 'Done' in Meta Business Inbox with New Conversation Routing
I'm encountering a problem with the transition from Facebook's Handover Protocol to the new Conversation Routing system. Previously, under the Handover Protocol, once the primary app (e.g., a chatbot) responded to a user query, the conversation would automatically move to the 'Done' directory. However, with the recent shift to Conversation Routing, this behaviour has changed. All conversations remain in the Main directory even though the default app has already replied to the user. This is causing difficulties for real agents using the Meta Business Inbox feature, as it's not clear whether a conversation is actively being handled by the bot or has been transferred to the Inbox app.
Current configuration: In my facebook page > Settings > Page Setup > Messenger Conversation Routing> Default App is set to my chatbot app In Page Setup > Advanced Messaging, I've tried both leaving the 'Primary Receiver for Handover Protocol' field empty and setting my app as the primary receiver
I also noted that once you setup a default app for Conversation Routing, you can't remove it anymore.
Question:
How can I ensure that conversations handled by the bot are marked as 'Done' once responded to, to maintain clarity for the agents in the Meta Inbox?  Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
